# How do I insert a Unicode character into a field at the cursor position

Tags: events, unicode, keyboard, livecode

I have a handler in a field which I want to use to insert a particular Unicode character when a key is pressed

```
   on rawKeyDown theKeyNumber   
      if theKeyNumber is 91 then  -- code 91 is '['
      -- insert Unicode character
      --   ɛ 
      -- = U025B, latin small letter open e
      -- or 603 in decimal
      -- at cursor position in the current field
      set the useUnicode to true
      put  unicode numToChar(603)  into selection
   else pass rawKeyDown -- don't forget this!
   end rawKeyDown
```

Thus I would like to insert a Unicode character instead of the character directly generated by the keyDown event and thus not pass on the keyDown event.

The example is adapted from the example for the 'rawKeyDown' message in the LiveCode dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the question. The code example now does the job.